# JWT Authentication error on Updating an item in MERN stack

Tags: javascript, jwt, mern

Can't update/edit. It's a basic MERN CRUD app with JWT, RTK, and MUI. When I try, I get

`PUT http://localhost:3000/api/purchases/[object%20Object] 401 (Unauthorized)      xhr.js:210`

in Chrome Dev Tools. Also I'm getting 2 error messages saying `Not Authorized tableForm.jsx:29` and `Not Authorized Table.jsx:17`

Those messages are originating from a console.log in my auth middleware, but only happen when updating. Get, Create, and Delete all work fine.

```
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token

    if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        try{
            //Get token from header
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
            //Verify token
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

            //Get user from the token
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select('-password')
            
            next()

        }   catch (error)   {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(401)
            throw new Error('Not authorizecd')
        }
    }
    if (!token) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('Not authorized, no token')
    }
} )
```

In Table and tableForm, I also have

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isError) {
console.log(message)
}
```

Maybe my Slice or Controller is wrong, but I've checked similar questions and projects on here and GitHub, so idk. Here, they are:

```
//Update Purchase
export const updatePurchase = createAsyncThunk(
    'purchases/update',
    async (purchaseData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
        return await purchaseService.updatePurchase(purchaseData, token)
    } catch (error) {
        const message =
            (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString()
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
})

//extra reducers part
.addCase(updatePurchase.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(updatePurchase.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false 
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.purchases = state.purchases.map((purchase) => purchase._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : purchase)
            })
            .addCase(updatePurchase.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false 
                state.isError = true
                state.message = action.payload
            })

//"Service" part
const updatePurchase = async (purchaseId, purchaseData, token) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }

    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + purchaseId, purchaseData, config)

    return response.data
}

//and the Controller
const updatePurchase = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const purchase = await Purchase.findById(req.params.id)

    if (!purchase){
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('Purchase not found')
    }

    //const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)

    //Check for user
    if(!req.user) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('User not found')
    }

    //Make sure the user matches the purchases
    if (purchase.user.toString() !==req.user.id) {
        res.status(401)
        throw new Error('User not authorized')
    }

    const updatedPurchase = await Purchase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
        new: true,
    })

    res.status(200).json(updatedPurchase)
})
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. I've tried everything and have been working on this for days, but I'm kind of new so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Here is the git repo if needed.
https://github.com/LazAustin/final_license_manager.git

Here is the front end where updatePurchase is used. I'm not sure what to pass anymore. The ID and/or the whole Purchase? Either way I've tried everything.

```
function EditForm({purchase}) {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(purchase.title);
    const [producer, setProducer] = useState(purchase.producer);
    ... //shortened for reading purposes
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState(purchase.notes);

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
    const onSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()
        const purchaseData = {
            title,
            producer
            ... //just shortening for reading purposes
            notes,
            id: purchase._id
        }

       dispatch(updatePurchase(purchaseData)) // <-tried different combinations of id and purchase on front and back end. 
//I think its supposed to be updatePurchase(purchase._id, purchaseData) and same on the slice but that didnt work either
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm! Figured it out, just in case anyone else rolls on this question. Forgot my id was set to "purchaseId" in the Service. Changed my service back to what I originally had it as (below). Then below that is my new front end with `purchaseId: purchase._id`

```
const updatePurchase = async (purchaseData, token) => {
    const { purchaseId, ...body } = purchaseData;
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }

    const response = await axios.put(API_URL + purchaseId, body, config)

    return response.data
}
```

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        const purchaseData = ({
           title,
           ...,
           notes,
           purchaseId: purchase._id
        })

       dispatch(updatePurchase(purchaseData))
    }
```